# Keyboard strange behavior

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have a ASUS R900V laptop, 1 year ago, I spilled a small amount of water over the keyboard, and it started behaving strangely, writes `aq` when I push `a` or `q` buttons, and some other thing like this...
I started using an external keyboard, and after a month it started working well again.
Now, after nearly a year, the keyboard started doing this crazy thing by itself againm I thought it was a hardware issue, so I brought my external keyboard again, but the strangest thing is that, the internal keyboard works fine for like a minute after I turn it on, also randomly sometimes, so maybe it's more like a software issue, but the problem is still even after formatting my pc

Comment: "But the problem is still even after formatting my pc" - It's a hardware problem. Clear your keyboard or replace.

Comment: what do you mean by clearing it ?

Comment: Open your keyboard and clean it, it may help.

Comment: ok, but how would you explain that it works fine for a moment ?

Comment: I had same issue, but it was typing randomly (works for an hour and then starts typing itself). Cleaning keyboard helped me. However, if you are not sure if it's a hardware problem, boot from a LiveCD/DVD like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install). If the problem still exists then it's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only distilled water doesn't have impurities that potentially contribute to electronics problems. Oxidation over the last year could just now be cropping up as part of a weak circuit, as ambient humidity changes, or maybe you just picked it up differently yesterday and a tiny conductive fragment flaked off somewhere.

There are some edge cases dismissed by trying another operating system but the choice probably is whether your time is best spent cleaning, paying someone to clean it, replacing the suspect hardware or just ignoring it and hoping for the best.